# No "src" folder in ASP.NET 5 Templates project

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc

I am using Visual Studio 2015 and it was strange that after creating a ASP.NET 5, I can't find any src folder in it.

[image: 1]

[image: 2]

How do I fix this?
My visual studio version is 14.0.23107.178.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is so simple and found it by myself

just tick the option to create directory for solution, when trying to create new project, that's all.

[image]